# How to prove that the set of recursive primitive functions is closed under

Tags: computability, primitive-recursion

the scheme of iteration ?

Here is the scheme of iteration : for $g : \mathbb{N}^p\to \mathbb{N}$ and $h:\mathbb{N}^{p+1}\to \mathbb{N}$ two primitive recursive functions we associate $f: \mathbb{N}^{p+1}\to \mathbb{N}$ defined by :

$f(\bar a, 0)=g(\bar a)\\ 
f(\bar a, x+1)=h(\bar a, f(\bar a, x)).$

Here is my attempt :

Let consider a primitive recursive function $F: \mathbb{N}^{p+1}\to \mathbb{N}$.

Then by the primitive recursion : $F(\bar a,0))=k(\bar a) \\
F(\bar a, x+1)= l(\bar a, x, F(\bar a,x))$ where $k$ and $l$ are recursive primitive functions.

We want $F$ to check the scheme of iteration. First we can take $k\equiv g$ and then how can make a link with $h$ and $l$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $l(\bar{a}, x, y) = h(\bar{a},y)$.
More precisely, writing $\pi_i$ for the $i$-th projection from $\mathbb{N}^{p+2}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, we see that $l$ is the composition of $h$ and projections, as follows:
$$
l(a_1, \ldots, a_p, x, y) =
h(\pi_1(a_1, \ldots, a_p, x, y), \ldots,
\pi_p(a_1, \ldots, a_p, x, y),
\pi_{p+2}(a_1, \ldots, a_p, x, y))
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering but the two functions do not have the same arity, so how can it be equal ? Moreover why do we have to take $y$ ? We cannot just put $F(\bar a, x)$ instead ?

Comment: The change in arity is accomplished by composing with projections. I'll add an explanation. No, you cannot put $F(\bar{a}, x)$ into the definition, because on the left-hand side $l$ must be applied to *variables*.

Comment: Thank you for the details ! In fact it is the function $h(\pi_1,...,\pi_p,\pi_{p+2}): \mathbb{N}^{p+2}\to \mathbb{N}$ which is recursive primitive by composition right ?

Comment: Just one thing, for instance if we want to prove that $add : \mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{N},(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is primitive recursive using the primitive recursion we have $add(x,0)= x = \pi_1^1 =k$ and $add(x,y+1)=x+(y+1)=s(x+y)= l(x,y,add(x,y))= s(\pi_{3}^{3}(x,y, add(x,y)))$ ? As you said the problem is that $add(x,y)$ is not a variable so should I write $l(x,y,x+y)$ or $l(x,y,t)$ instead ?

Comment: You should write $l(x,y,t)$. When you *substitute* $x + y$ for $t$ you will get the desired equation.

Comment: Ok thank you for the precisions !